# Validating Form in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to show client side error when user try to submit form I check the validators and if its not according to validation rule It show red box arround the input field. What is the good way to do this? and how to do?

### html

```html
<button type="button" class="btn-u pull-right margin-bottom-10" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"><span class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Invite User</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Invite User</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" id='myForm' role="form" [ngFormModel]="InviteUserForm">
                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.username' class="form-control" ngControl="username">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
                        <input type="email" required [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.email' class="form-control" ngControl="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
                    </div>

                    <div class="input-group margin-bottom-20">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-glass"></i></span>
                        <select [(ngModel)]='inviteUser.partnerId' class="form-control" ngControl="partner">
                            <option>Select one</option>
                            <option *ngFor="let partner of _partners" value={{partner.Id}}>
                                {{partner.Name}}
                            </option>
                        </select>

                    </div>

                </form>
                <button type="button" class="btn-u btn-u-default margin-right-5" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" [disabled]="!InviteUserForm.valid" class="btn-u pull-right" (click)="Invite(inviteUser)" data-dismiss="modal">Invite</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

### component

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm }    from '@angular/forms';
import { FORM_PROVIDERS, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, Control} from '@angular/common';
import {UserService} from '../../services/user.service';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router }  from '@angular/router';
import { HttpHelper} from '../../utils/httphelper.utils';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import {InviteModel} from '../../models/invite.model';

import {LocalStorageService} from '../../services/localStorage.service';
@Component({
    selector: 'invite-user',
    templateUrl: '../../app/components/user/invite-user.html',
    providers: [UserService, HttpHelper, LocalStorageService]
})

export class InviteUserComponent {
    InviteUserForm: ControlGroup;
    private _partners: Observable<any[]>;
    private name: string;
    private email: string;
    private partner: number;
    private _data: Observable<any[]>;
    inviteUser: InviteModel;

    constructor(
        @Inject(FormBuilder) public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        @Inject(UserService) private _userService: UserService,
        @Inject(LocalStorageService) private _localStorageService: LocalStorageService) {

        this.inviteUser = new InviteModel();
        this.InviteUserForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            'username': new Control('', Validators.required),
            'email': new Control('', Validators.compose([Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$'), Validators.required])),
            'partner': new Control('', Validators.required)
        });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this._userService.partners()
            .subscribe(data => this._partners = data,
            error => {
                console.log("error while retriving partners");
                this._userService.handleError(error);
            }
            );
    }

    Invite(inviteUser) {
        console.log(inviteUser);
        this._userService.inviteUser(inviteUser)
            .subscribe(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this._data = data;
                this.inviteUser = new InviteModel();
            },
            error => {
                console.log("error while retriving partners");
                this._userService.handleError(error);
            },
            () => {
                this._localStorageService.setValue('notifications', 'Info Are You sure to Delete this Entry');
                this.inviteUser = new InviteModel();
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `css class` for it and angular2 automatically handles it for you.

If you are doing any custom thing or custom validation, you have to be sure to add `class` accordingly,

reference : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms-deprecated.html

```
.ng-valid[required] {
  border-left: 5px solid #42A948; /* green */
}

.ng-invalid {
  border-left: 5px solid #a94442; /* red */
}
```

Comment: when form load it shows red input fields. I want First time to not show green and red fields. What to do to achieve this?? @micronyks

Comment: Thats because when page n form is loaded it puts ng-invalid class to different controls.

Comment: I haven't tried anything for this requirement so need some time to think on this issue.